# Reverse Proxy Apache - which SSL Certificates are needed on which device?

Tags: apache, ssl, reverse-proxy

I am developing a system where controlled access to an origin server is required. Due to the use scenarios certificates and client certificate authentication is the most preferable way of authenticating clients.

It is not possible to give each client their own certificate for several reasons. Instead, they have assumed access by being on the same local network as a Reverse Proxy 1. For example:

```
Client(s) -- [http] --> Reverse Proxy 1 (RP1) [Apache] -- [https, internet] --> Reverse Proxy 2 (RP2) [Apache] -- [http] --> Content Origin Server
```

Here, RP1 sits on the Client network. It passes all requests to RP2 on the Origin network.

Connections to the origin server are only allowed from RP2, which authenticates its own connections using SSL certificates. I have this chain working with HTTP throughout, but as soon as I enable SSL I cannot connect. I think it is due to my setup of Apache and the various SSL certificates.

My questions are:

1. Which SSL settings / proxy settings are required for this type of 'double' reverse proxy to work with Apache (i.e. on RP1 and RP2)?
2. Which SSL certificates need to be generated and which certificates should be placed on each server (RP1/RP2 in this case)?

I wish to self-sign the certificates using my own certificate authority.

My current Apache settings are as follows (I will limit the number of listen ports etc... once I have a working system):

RP1:

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
    #ProxyPreserveHost On
    SSLEngine On
    SSLProxyEngine on
    SSLProxyCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ca.pem
    SSLProxyMachineCertificateFile /etc/apache2/proxy-client.pem

#   RequestHeader set SSL_CLIENT_CERT ""
    <Location />
#           RequestHeader set SSL_CLIENT_CERT "%{SSL_CLIENT_CERT}s"
            ProxyPass https://x.x.x.x:yyyy/
            ProxyPassReverse https://x.x.x.x:yyyy/
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

RP2 (x.x.x.x):

```
Listen yyyy https
<VirtualHost *:*>

SSLEngine On

# Set the path to SSL certificate
# Usage: SSLCertificateFile /path/to/cert.pem
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/server.cer
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/server.key
SSLVerifyClient require
SSLVerifyDepth 2
SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/ca.cer


# Servers to proxy the connection, or;
# List of application servers:

ProxyPass / http://a.a.a.a:zzzz/
ProxyPassReverse / http://a.a.a.a:zzzz/

# Or, balance the load:
# ProxyPass / balancer://balancer_cluster_name

</VirtualHost>
```

Certificates are named uniquely. So in this case ca.pem on RP1 is the .pem from ca.cer on RP2.